# Consuming .net SOAP Service on BlackBerry PlayBook

Tags: apache-flex, soap, wsdl, cxf, blackberry-playbook

I am looking for approaches I can take to consume my .net SOAP service on the BlackBerry Playbook. So far I believe there are two main approaches to my problem.

**Apache CXF wsdl2js**
I have used wsdl2js to generate the javascript needed to communicate with the service. However I end up getting a http 500 error and have not been able to get past that. I have looked through the provided examples from the Apache CXF download and I have done some searching and cannot find a solid example of creating the javascript client. A lot of examples seem to somehow access the wsdl file at runtime from a server but my javascript is already generated from the CXF tool and I just include the scripts... if anyone has some tips here that would be great.

**Adobe Flex and AS3**
Another option I have considered is using Adobe Flex. I create a new Mobile Flex project in Flash Builder using the BlackBerry PlayBook SDK and Flex 4.5. However when I use the menu options to connect to a web service I get prompted with "This option is only available for flex projects."

Are there any other options out there that provide a solution to this problem? If you need more information just let me know.I understand this is a large topic, thank you for your time.

Comment: I wanted to add; that an Adobe Flash Builder update in June should have significantly better support for using Flash Builder to build Playbook apps.  It is expected to coincide with AIR 2.7.  I know it sucks to wait; but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

In Flex, you can use the [WebService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/mxml/WebService.html) class to access SOAP WebServices.  [More info here.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_3.html).  I'm sure you can use [this class for a non-Flex AS3 solution](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/WebService.html).

I'm not sure why they disable the Flash Builder tooling for this; but it shouldn't prevent you from using the actual classes to access WebServices.

I can't speak about the alternate approaches.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but I do not have enough rep to vote for you even though it was quite useful. By the lack of responses I may end up just making an ASP.NET web app because the PlayBook has the option to hide the browsers chrome. Since its an internal application I think that's fine. But hopefully I get some more input.

Comment: @Visualrise Media It all depends what you want to do; I wouldn't consider a web app a replacement for a native app. If the lack of Web Services support in an IDE is driving you away from Flex; I have to wonder what were the decisions behind choosing the technology in the first place. Since the Playbook supports Flash in the browser; why not create a browser based Flex app.

Comment: We have a multi-touch dashboard developed in C#. It is a WPF application. It gets its data from a service that we also created. The PlayBook application is more like an extra thing for a presentation. What would the difference be between a jQuery/CSS/HTML5 app and a Flex app in the browser? I'm new to a lot of these technologies.

Comment: @Visualrise Media Probably a book could be written on the difference between JavaScript/CSS/HTML and Flash. I'd say Flash is better for cross platform /multi device development. If you only care about the Playbook; that isn't a reason to chose.  I'd say that Flash/Flex has better tooling, better debugging facilities, and better profiling options for performance optimization. Also I feel the Flex framework has a more robust component set than what you can find w/ JavaScript.  I'm not sure if JavaScript can consume a SOAP web service natively. (JSON is a more common transfer format)